# Only add unique record in db column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there an option I can select in SQL management studio, when an int is entered into a it must be unique from all the other columns in that table.

Id Name Code
1  John 3545
2  Mark 454
3 Jim   989

If the user tried to create an account:
4 Mick 3545 - this would fail?

Comment: You could always do a select to find out what's there.  But that's never going to be reliable.  You should always let the DB set up unique IDs for you (auto increment).

Comment: It looks like the OP already has an identity column with "Id".  You can do what Akash specified and add a unique constraint to the "Code" column.  A common example for this is when you want to restrict duplicate usernames for an app.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `UNIQUE` constraints on the columns which you want unique

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName UNIQUE (ColumnName); 
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for sounds like an Identity column.  If you make your primary key an identity, you don't need to worry about inserting it - it is auto-incremented with inserts and guaranteed to be unique.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    //...
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) is more documentation on the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Make Code primary key in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add `unique` constraint as part of column definition.  Note that if column is primary key, it is unique by definition.  See [MSDN Create Table page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), section on column constraints.